# Date Select Error in Ektron

Tags: forms, validation, ektron

I have a form that is using the calendar/date selection tool within Ektron, but when users select the current date (or any date, for that matter), it gives an error saying that you need to select a date in the past.

We haven't tooled around in the code for this form, but it almost sounds like a validation issue.

Here's the code, as is, from Ektron.

```
<p align="center" style="text-align: left;">Date program was presented:&#160;
<ektdesignns_calendar title="Date presented" id="Date_presented" onblur="design_validate_xpath('number(translate(.,\'-\',\'\')) &lt;= number(translate($currentDate,\'-\',\'\'))',this,'Date in the past (required)');" ektdesignns_name="Date_presented" ektdesignns_caption="Date presented" ektdesignns_invalidmsg="Date in the past (required)" ektdesignns_validate="xpath:number(translate(.,'-','')) &lt;= number(translate($currentDate,'-',''))" ektdesignns_basetype="calendar" ektdesignns_datatype="date" ektdesignns_validation="datePast-req" name="Date_presented">
<input type="text" size="30" readonly="readonly" unselectable="on" />
<img width="16" height="16" class="design_fieldbutton" alt="Select date" src="[skinpath]btncalendar.gif" unselectable="on" /></ektdesignns_calendar></p>
```

My knowledge on validation is limited, but it looks like it's parsing the date as an integer. Is it possible to add a day (+1) to the current date so that it interprets any day as valid as long as it's not in the future?

Comment: Since Ektron is a .NET application, why did you tag this with Java and PHP?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a HTML form as opposed to a Smart form?

If so, have you checked the validation settings on the calendar field?  If you edit the form, right-click on the field and choose Field Properties you will get the properties window.  Go to the Validation tab and check the setting in the Validation drop down.

There are options for ensuring the date is in the past or the future.  Perhaps one of these options has been set?

Comment: Agree with this. Someone has likely set validation on the field. You can see the validation code in the output you pasted in: design_validate_xpath('number(translate(.,\'-\',\'\')) &lt;= number(translate($currentDate,\'-\',\'\'))'